# Force iteration range to be under a symbol

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

Given:

```
\begin{equation}
    out =  \displaystyle \oplus_{i = 1 ... l} r_i
\end{equation}
```

How can I force `\oplus` to place `i = 1 ... l` to be strictly **under** the oplus symbol?

Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}    
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\text{out} = \mathop{\oplus}\limits_{i = 1 \ldots l} r_i
\end{equation}  

\begin{equation}
\text{out} = \mathop{\oplus}\limits_{\mathclap{i = 1 \ldots l}} r_i
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
    \mathrm{out} =  \bigoplus_{i = 1 \ldots l} r_i
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`\oplus` is designed as an infix binary operator, `\bigoplus` is designed as a prefix operator (the same distinction as `+` and `\sum`)

Note in your original `\displaystyle` is not needed as that is the default in `equation`, also multiletter identifiers such as `out` should be set as `\mathrm` (or `\mathit` if you want italic)